# Count clicks from 1 to 3 and then repeat?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to loop my clicks from 1 to 3 and then it should repeat. I try something like this

```
$(".switch").click(function(){
  var $btn = $(".click_count");
  var count = ($btn.data(".click_count") || 0) + 1;
  $btn.data(".click_count", count);
  if ( count == 1 )
    $btn.text("2");
  else if ( count == 2 )
    $btn.text("3");
  else {
    $btn.text("1");
  }
  return false;
});
```

**My problem:** How can I repeat this function, so that click no. 4 will show no. 2 aso. again?

Comment: `count %= 3;` :)

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol Yes, my fail ;) - thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use modular arithmetic:

```
var count = (($btn.data(".click_count") || 0) + 1) % 3;
```

EDIT: also you don't need those ifs:

```
$btn.data(".click_count", count);
$btn.text(count + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight modification from Albert, you need to do this.

```
var count = (($btn.data(".click_count") || 0)%3) + 1;
```

because you need 1,2,3 not 0